# Android intents won't start the next activities

Tags: android, templates, android-intent, android-activity

**Application & problem Description**
We're trying to create a text-based android-game (don't ask ;-)  ), and we're having trouble starting a new activity through an intent for some reason. Our game starts with a welcome screen --> new game (button) --> class selection (two buttons, detective/murderer) --> first game activity

The ingame activities will contain an imageview, a text-view a continue-button (leading to the next acitivity) and most often a back-button (boolean value, depending on game/story context).

The problem is, that we cannot get our continue button to start the next activity, even though we use almost the same code as we do from the menu to the first game acitivity? Our idea is, that we have both layout templates and a content template, and that we can create new activities where we just set the variables for the picture resource, the string resource, a boolean for the back-button and the following activity to be started by "continue".

**Code**
This is our code:

ContentTemplate:

```
package com.bsnoire;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContentTemplate extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
protected int image, back, text;
protected Class<? extends Activity> cls;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setVariables();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.contentImageView);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentTextView);
    Button bBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contentbBack);

    iv.setImageResource(image);
    tv.setText(text);
    bBack.setVisibility(back);
}



@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    this.finish();
}

//===============================================================================

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.contentbBack:
        this.finish();
        break;

    case R.id.contentbCon:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, cls);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;


    }
}

public void setVariables() 
{

}

}
```

Act1 (i.e. activity 1)

```
package com.bsnoire;

import com.bsnoire.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Act1 extends ContentTemplate 
{


/**
 * Sets the variables in Act1
 */
@Override
public void setVariables()
{

    image = R.drawable.p1;
    back = 0;
    text = R.string.A1S1;
    cls = com.bsnoire.Act2.class;
}

}
```

Act2 will be the same as 1, but with other variables. In the menu, we refer to Act1 with the following code (switch-function):

```
case R.id.bAbout:
Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Act1.class);
startActivity(intent2);
break;
```

Which works!

We don't get any compilation errors, and no run-time errors. Nothing happens when pressing "continue" in Act1, except the green marking when the finger clicks it.

Comment: I should mention, that we've tried to hardcode Act1 and Act2 (removing the 'generic' aspect of us just having to set the variables, and just repeating everything). This results in the exact same stand-still in Act1.

Comment: Add the OnClickListener to your button ..., i think that you have to add Log to see if your onClick is being called.

Comment: Thanks, but after trying it out, it didn't help. Also, the log message doesn't show up in logcat, only some standard messages: "onTouchEvent".

We find that odd, as the device registers the touch input, but won't write our log which is placed just before the intent is declared and sent in the listener.

(We use the command   Log.d("BSNoire", "Continue button clicked")  )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

1. `Button bCon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contentbCon);`
2. `bCon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
      public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent newscr = new Intent(ContentTemplate.this, NextClassYouWantToShow.class);
      startActivity(newscr);
      }
   });`

Comment: Thanks, zkminusck, you had the same idea as Anis in the comments to #0. Sadly, it didn't work. Nothing changed, no new errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to android and Android Studio, but I was having similar issues that I was able to resolve.  I do not know how or why my solution works, only that it did in my case.  I had some activities that started fine and others that did not.  I noticed that all of the activities that started fine had `onCreate` methods with only a **Bundle** as input,

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     ...
 }
```

While the activities that did not start were all ListActivities that had `onCreate` methods with a **Bundle** and **PersistableBundle**,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistedState){
  ...
}
```

I used Android Studio to auto-complete all of my `onCreate` methods so I do not know why they auto-completed differently.  However, when I removed the **PersistableBundle** from the non-starting `onCreate` methods the activities started.